# read items from json array

Tags: php, json

I am trying to display tram times received as json from an online API. The json I am receiving is the following:

```
    Array
    (
    [@odata.context] => 
 https://opendataclientapi.azurewebsites.net/odata/$metadata#Metrolinks(StationLocation,Id,Dest1,Wait1,Dest2,Wait2,Dest3,Wait3,MessageBoard)
    [value] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [StationLocation] => Deansgate - Castlefield
                    [Id] => 272
                    [Dest1] => 
                    [Wait1] => 
                    [Dest2] => 
                    [Wait2] => 
                    [Dest3] => 
                    [Wait3] => 
                    [MessageBoard] => Today Manchester City welcome Liverpool to the Etihad Stadium. KO is at 19:45 and services are expected to be busier than usual. Please plan your journey ahead.
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [StationLocation] => Deansgate - Castlefield
                    [Id] => 458
                    [Dest1] => East Didsbury
                    [Wait1] => 0
                    [Dest2] => Altrincham
                    [Wait2] => 2
                    [Dest3] => 
                    [Wait3] => 
                    [MessageBoard] => Today Manchester City welcome Liverpool to the Etihad Stadium. KO is at 19:45 and services are expected to be busier than usual. Please plan your journey ahead.
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [StationLocation] => Deansgate - Castlefield
                    [Id] => 459
                    [Dest1] => Piccadilly
                    [Wait1] => 3
                    [Dest2] => Etihad Campus
                    [Wait2] => 4
                    [Dest3] => 
                    [Wait3] => 
                    [MessageBoard] => Today Manchester City welcome Liverpool to the Etihad Stadium. KO is at 19:45 and services are expected to be busier than usual. Please plan your journey ahead.
                )

        )

)
```

How do I get each individual item such as StationLocation, Dest1 and Wait1?

At the moment I am using the following loop but it just results in all records being returned

```
$results = json_decode($response->getBody(),true);
foreach($results->Array as $result) {
       print_r($result);
    }
```

Comment: There is no JSON in the posted code. You correctly decode the input JSON using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with `TRUE` as its second argument but that's all about JSON in this question. Your question is about PHP arrays. Read about PHP [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in the documentation and don't stop until you reach the section about ["accessing items using the square brackets syntax"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it, you echo the array element:

```
$results = json_decode($response->getBody(),true);
foreach($results->Array as $result) {
   // for example echo $result['element_in_array'];
   echo $result['StationLocation'];
}
```